# 14.04.2 LTS booting to black tty screen after i was forced to hard restart

Tags: boot, tty

I attempted to restart my Lenovo T400, and my laptop just sat there on the desktop, not responding. so after a hard restart, there was this error that there was some sort of error with my "temporary folder". i thought nothing of it and skipped whatever setup or fix it was attempting to do. now my system boots up to the ubuntu screen, but then goes straight to this black TTY/Kernel screen. tried a couple options off of here to no avail, and I've only seen one problem that's remotely similar to what I'm seeing here..

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> takes me to a blank black screen and nothing happens.

[image]

after logging into my username, it tells me:

```
"no talloc stackfram at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I need some more clarification. You say you try to put in your password. Have you first put in your username. At the tty screen you will think you are logged in but you are not. You need first the username and then the password. Then after that you can `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as a first shot.

Comment: first of all, thank you so much for responding. this is rather frustrating. i've only used Ubuntu for 2 years or so, and have never seen this kernel screen before and i'm kind of panicked. so when i enter my username/password, it tells me 


"no talloc stackfram at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory"

after entering sudo dpkg --configure -a it says http://imgur.com/5yzJNZP

Answer (score 1):

Ok that is good.  The talloc error sometimes is fixed as below.

```
sudo apt-get purge libpam-smbpass
```

It is related to pam authentication on Samba Shares

Now back to the other problems.  It appears that you may have a broken or misconfigured kernel.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
```

-f looks for missing dependencies

If all of that fails then reboot to recovery options on the grub screen and try an older kernel.

Comment: okay, so i tried all of these things. and this is what happened


http://imgur.com/jQWzVqK

Comment: also: tried "pam-auth-update" and removed SMB password synchronization..but it says "DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debonconf/config.dat-new: permission denied"